# What kind of padding should AES use?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, block, padding

I have implemented the AES encryption (homework), but I stumble upon the problem of padding the messages.

If my messages are arrays of bytes as such:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) {
    int size = (int) Math.ceil(message.length / 16.0);
    byte[] result = new byte[size * 16];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if ((i+1) * 16 > message.length){
            //padding here????
        } else {
            byte[] block = Arrays.copyOfRange(message, i * 16, (i + 1) * 16);
            byte[] encryptedBlock = encryptBlock(block);                
            System.arraycopy(encryptedBlock, 0, result, i*16, 16);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I pad such a message?

I cannot use Zero Padding because the each byte could be zero, and it might affect such a message with trailing zeros.

I cannot find any reference to how is this done not even [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) (the paper describing the AES encryption)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of methods you can use, from simple to advanced. Bruce Schneier suggests two rather simple methods:

One is to pad the last block with n bytes all with value n, which is what Alex Wien suggested. This has issues (including restricting you to block sizes that are less than 256 bytes long). This padding mode is known as PKCS#7 padding (for 16 byte blocks) or PKCS#5 padding (for 8 byte blocks).

The other is to append a byte with value 0x80 (a byte with value 1000 0000 in binary) followed by as many zero bytes as needed to fill the last block. This method is known as ISO padding, which is short for ISO/IEC 9797-1 padding method 2. The padding itself is bit-level padding, a single bit valued 1 is added, and then add 0 valued bits until you reach the block size.

As for how to know whether a message is padded, the answer is a message will *always* be padded: even if the last chunk of the message fits perfectly inside a block (i.e. the size of the message is a multiple of the block size), you will have to add a dummy last block.

If you are interested in researching some of the more advanced methods, look up a technique called ciphertext stealing on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing

Comment: How does it match with NIST standards when we follow different padding methods? AFAIK, we use `PKCS#7` padding when the input data is less than 128 bits. But that doesn't seem to match with the expected results (at least in my case. And for verification, I went to http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick with padding:

You should pad with the byte represntation of the length of the padding:

333

or

4444

or 999999999

Then when you read the firstpadding  byte later, you know how many bytes are left to read.

Comment: how do i know if the message was or was not padded ?

Comment: You read the last byte, if there is 0, then it was not padded, or similar, otherwise you remove the number of bytes represnedt by the last byte. But think of N-1 ür N +1. i dont wan to think of that now,.

Comment: Ok, this is how I understand if the message does not require padding I should add a whole block of zeros, if it does I append the byte representation of the length of the padding

Comment: This "trick" only works if your block size is less than 256 bytes; if it's not, then what? I personally don't like this padding technique.

Comment: 256 byte will ever extend to 257 byte; Ever read the last byte, is 0, ok take 0  -255; is not 0, then remove th last n+1.

Comment: I'm sorry Alex, but your representation of the padding bytes leaves much to be desired, and your comments seem to be completely off mark.

Comment: @RexLakio: The point is the message is [*always*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3) padded, and the padding byte tells you how many padding bytes there are. Alex's comment about using 0 in the case of no padding doesn't really make sense.