# How to encrypt String or JSON

Tags: go, encryption

I am trying to encrypt some text in Go using this code:

```
key, _ := hex.DecodeString("6368616e676520746869732070617373")
plaintext := []byte("exampleplaintext")
if len(plaintext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
    panic("plaintext is not a multiple of the block size")
}
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext)
```

I am getting this result:

```
891cf7c418d2d1cd4e5c9db05b092e50d5a25e9e4ce4f5f799efdb82596e32a9
```

[Link](https://play.golang.org/p/Dg3LCFRuw2S) to the code above in golang play

Everything is working fine but when I am adding spaces and line break to the input it is not working I am getting error:

```
panic: plaintext is not a multiple of the block size
```

[Link](https://play.golang.org/p/hdnURdWjN-O) to the code

My question is if I have to encode a string like this:

```
t := ` {
    "mobileNum": "9999999999",
    "osVersion": "",
    "AppId": "hhhhhh88888",
    "panNo": "AXXXXXXXXX",
    "osType": "",
    "emailId": "nxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "deviceID": ""
}`
```

Then what should I do?

Comment: Your code is just missing the goal a bit.
Basicaly in AES you have a blocksize and AES can only deal with bytes slice where their length is a multiple of the blocksize, so for a len of 25 you should bring the length to 32 (the upper next block size).

Comment: My question is very simple so there should not be any confusion one is working and other is not working and what should I do?

Comment: Also it seems your strategy is to append nul bytes to match the blocksize, that might not seems but this is dangerous (yes crypto is unfair :) ), you should try to use a padding algoritm (that will also keep your data intact) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572751/8537707

Comment: Please refer [Golang-AES encryption (CBC mode, PKCS7 padding)](https://www.programmersought.com/article/6109709437/)

Comment: This is not the answer you want to hear, but please don't do such stuff yourself, especially if you are unsure about how crypto works. Please use prepacked common tooling e.g. golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox

Comment: @Volker where can I find common tooling in golang I haven't found any tools that is why I am trying it.

Comment: @NilaySingh I gave you that tooling: golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox What more  do you need? What part of NaCl is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

AES can only deal with byte slice where the len is a multiple of his blocksize.
So you should ceil your len to the next block size.
That will add some null bytes to fill in the gap, even if this seams reasonable this isn't for 2 reasons :

- This corrupt your data (for json might not be a problem but if you are dealing with let's say a video file that a problem).
- This is dangerous (yes crypto is unfair :) ), this does not reveal your whole key but simplify attacks.

For an example you can take a look at https://gist.github.com/huyinghuan/7bf174017bf54efb91ece04a48589b22, this example uses AES and PCKS for padding.